# XmlTextReader.Read() does not read all lines

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file from which I want to read all lines with `XmlTextReader`. Here is an example of the xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSigns>
  <CodeSign Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>AAA</Title>
      <Shortcut>AAA</Shortcut>
      <Description>AAA</Description>
      <Author>Viva</Author>
      <LoadTypes>
        <LoadType>Expansion</LoadType>
      </LoadTypes>
    </Header>
    <Sign>
      <Declarations />
      <Code Language="SQL Server" Kind="SQL Server"><![CDATA[SELECT TOP 100 [Id]
       ,[TotalSeconds]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Parameters] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [Parameters]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Query] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [Query]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [StackTrace] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [StackTrace]
       ,[CreateDate]
       ,[MachineName]
       ,[UserName]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Exception] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [Exception]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [InnerException] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [InnerException]
       ,[CommandType]
       FROM [QMaster].[dbo].[LogSlowQueries]
       where CreateDate > CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
       order by totalseconds desc]]>
      </Code>
    </Sign>
  </CodeSign>
</CodeSigns>
```

Some elements don't matter for us and the problem happens when reading from the `Code` element because just three lines were read instead of all.

The code C# used for reading this file is given below:

```cs
public void Load(string path) {

  filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
  try {
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path)) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
          switch (reader.Name) {
            case "Title":
              title = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;
            case "ToolTip":
              tooltip = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;
            case "Description":
              description = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;
            case "Author":
              author = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;                
            case "Code":
              language = reader.GetAttribute("Language");
              code = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;               
          }
        }
      }
    }       
  }
  catch (XmlException) {
  }
}



private string ReadProperty(XmlReader reader) {

  if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
    return string.Empty;

  reader.Read();
  return reader.Value;
}
```

We need to obtain all lines from the `XmlNodeType.Element` with the name `Code`, however, `reader.Value` returns ONLY the three lines in the picture:

[image]

Please help

Comment: the method Read() is reading to the closing angle bracket. Xml ignored returns so the data following the closing angle bracket is a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally find using Linq2Xml easier. With the help of XPath:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

var title = (string)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/CodeSigns/CodeSign/Header/Title");
var author = (string)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/CodeSigns/CodeSign/Header/Author");
var code = (string)xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/CodeSigns/CodeSign/Sign/Code");
```

OR

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
var topElem = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/CodeSigns/CodeSign");

var title = (string)topElem.XPathSelectElement("Header/Title");
var author = (string)topElem.XPathSelectElement("Header/Author");
var code = (string)topElem.XPathSelectElement("Sign/Code");
```